# Best way to compute offsets with moving targets

Tags: algorithm, assembly

It seems like there should be a standardized solution to this. Basically the problem is that I want to be able to compute whether or not I should use a near jump or a far jump. As in:

```
jump_to_near:
  ; ... lots of ops ...

jump_to_near:
    e9 24 ff ff ff          jmpq   1f22 <jump_to_far>
    eb f9                   jmp    1ff9 <jump_to_near>
```

The near jump opcode seems to be two bytes, while the far jump opcode is five. The question is, how can I know which one to use if the jump-to label comes **after** the actual opcode? Is there a standardized algorithm for computing something with tight dependencies like this, in particular given the case there may be lots of jumps where changing the opcode size of one may then affect other jumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not saying this is the only solution, but for several compilers for domain specific languages I have written, I have used the following strategy with success:

For all forward jumps initially assume that the target can be reached with a short jump.

Later, during back-patching, if a target turns out not to be reachable after all using a short jump, mark that jump as requiring a near jump and start the code-gen over for the routine in question.

-

It is also possible (yes, I have actually done this) to emit all near jumps (the long form) and then record any information that needs to be fixed up in the block in case you later find out you can and want to convert a particular jump from the near to the short form.

-

The first strategy is usually far simpler to implement.

Comment: Actually, I really like that second option. I may try that out, thanks!

Comment: That's cool. In my experience the vast majority of targets can actually be reached with a short jump, but that obviously varies depending on both the source language and the coding style (as well as other factors, like inlining).

Comment: Yeah, in my current implementation I cache all of the opcodes, before emitting them to memory. So it's easy to go from the extended version to the simplified version in one extra pass. Much easier than going the other way around (hence the original question). If I miscalculate one or two once in a while (false negative test for short range) it isn't that big a deal. But yeah, I assume that in general most jumps should be short. Appreciate the help!